# Add product to cart on website before it is live

Tags: javascript

Hello I am looking to add a product to my cart on kicksusa.com using a product ID code. The ID code is 349008 and I was wondering how I could add early by altering the code of the webpage. Thank you.

so far i have this link as adding the product

http://www.kicksusa.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/,,/product/349008/form_key/wf3zkNJLvH0W7uCi/

i need to fill in a form key though.  The form key varies based on your IP address.

Comment: www.kicksusa*com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/,,/product/349008/form_key/wf3zkNJLvH0W7uCi/

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: this is what i have so far...  http://www.kicksusa.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/,,/product/349008/form_key/wf3zkNJLvH0W7uCi/           you need to fill in a unique form key which you find in the page's source code

Answer (score 0):

You could only alter a local copy of the webpage, not the actual site. So you can not change their site, nor add this item unless their un-altered site will allow you to already, which I assume it doesn't, because otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question.